# Bypass Microsoft pin after restoring from a windows Image Backup?

Tags: windows-10

I am using Windows 10 on a dedicated DAW (digital audio workstation) laptop which is never connected to the internet.

I performed a major update to one of my software and it caused some issues so, as I keep backups in the form of Windows Image Backups, I restored an earlier image but, and it has never done this before, when I boot my device I now get the following message at the login screen:
“your pin is no longer available due to a change the security settings on this device."

As I understand it, windows want some kind of PIN associated with my online MS account and needs to connect to the internet but as I have previous said, this machine is not connected to the net and the wi-fi options are disabled so I could not connect even if I want to.
Also I do not remember setting a MS PIN that is associated with my account, I may have, but I do not remember doing so.

Yes, I could do a clean install but then I would have to reinstall the audio programs and go through the pain in the rear process of trying to offline apply all of the licences, and then setting it all up to work as it should - a day or so work.

I have no idea why this has happened as I have been able to restore from my Windows Image Backups before and not once did I get this error.

After google searches and youtube videos, nothing works.

When I created the Windows Image Backups I also created a USB boot drive at the same time.

I have tried booting to the USB and then from the recovery menu > Command prompt and enabled the Built-in Administrator Account

I then did the same but booted to safe mode first

I tried from the login screen, select and hover over "restart", hold down the shift key and click restart, and then enabling the built-in Admin Account

And there have been a fair number of variations that I have tried but nothing works.

So right now I have a very expensive but un-accessible machine and clients waiting for completed work that should have been sent to them today.

Can anyone suggest anything because I am at my wits end?

Comment: Use Microsoft Live to add a Password to your Microsoft account and use that.  I keep both Password and PIN and one or the other always works.

Comment: the wi-fi options are disabled so I could not connect even if I want to.      ......  Ethernet or Ethernet dongle does (almost all the time) not require configuration.

Comment: Simplest solution is to enable the built-in Administrator account to diagnose the issue fully

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Can not use Microsoft live as the laptop wont let me login to windows to enter one - when you click on the "Set up my Pin" it tries to connect to the net.

Comment: Ethernet and so on is disabled - its a custom built DAW with no network or otherwise capabilities.

Comment: As I described above - I tried enabling the built-in Administrator account but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

All solutions offered have not worked

> Add password. Connect by Ethernet. (All network devices disabled). Use
> built-in Admin Account.

So at this point, unfortunate or otherwise, you are going to have to re-install Windows.

When you reinstall Windows, I strongly suggest leaving a way to access a completely broken operating system.

Answer (score -1):

I have had issues with the PIN in the past too. To get back into the system, I suggest using a USB device with a Windows installer copy on it. You don't need to reinstall Windows, you can try this:

- Run the setup, select your language and keyboard layout.
- Choose to recover your installation.
- In the recovery menu you need to navigate to advanced options and look for the command prompt. This will run a command promt as system (TrustedInstaller) giving you access to all files when you don't use bitlocker.
- In the command promt you have to figure out what drive letter is your Windows installation. To do this you can try "dir :" and see if it contains the files that are on your installation. Let's say "dir E:" returns a list containing a folder named "Windows" for example.
- If you found the letter, type in the letter like so "E:".
- Next enter "cd E:\Windows\System32"
- Type in "del Utilman.exe"
- After that "copy cmd.exe Utilman.exe"
- Close the command prompt and reboot into Windows.

What that does it replace the accessibility application with a command prompt. After having done that you can go to the login screen of your Windows installation and click the accessibility icon in the bottom right of the login screen. A command prompt should show up, and from here you can run `lusrmgr.msc` to manage the accounts, enable the admin account or change the password.

If you can't manage to get into the user without pin even after trying multiple methods to enable password login you can always create a new account until you have the other one working again.

Comment: Considering it's over a year old question I'm pretty sure the OP has moved forward :-)